# Solving the equation X = AX + B of languages for X

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I'm currently working on the following problem for my computer theory class. It goes as follows:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be regular expressions. Show then that $A^* B$ is the
>   solution of $X = AX + B$.

Am I supposed to let $X = A^*B$? If so then

$$A^* B = A(A^* B) + B$$

I can understand that $A(A^* B)$ could be reduced to $A^*B$ but what happens with the ${}+ B$ part of the expression?

I've read up on Kleene algebra and found an axiom that seems relevant in which

$$b + ax \leq x \Rightarrow a^∗b \leq x $$

but I'm not actually sure if it applies.